# What are various types of Snanam (bathing)?

Tags: rituals, practice

Which scripture describes **Muni Snanam**, **Deva Snanam**, **Manava Snanam** and **Rakshasa Snanam** (bathing)?

Additionally, which scripture mentions about Vaaruna Snanam, Mantra Snanam, Dhivya Snanam, Kriya Snanam, Aagneya Snanam, Vaaya Veeya Snanam, Prokshana Snanam, Gowna Snanam, Kaapila Snanam, Nitya Snanam, Naimithiga Snanam, Shethra Ganga Snanam, Malaharsha Snanam, Kriyaanga Snanam, Kaamya Snanam etc.?

Note: Only scriptural reference is needed not detailed description so it's not too broad.

Comment: What's up with is I-R tag? :banghead: actually Scripture is also a valid tag for this one bcoz u are asking "What are the different types of bathing according to scriptures ...?" but I am afraid of ugly edit wars that are happening in recent times. So not adding a correct tag :O

Comment: Adding a scripture tag is like seventh finger here. It's implicit that OP asks about scriptures only. Is OP asking about you or me? Add a Sarvabhouma tag or other user tag?  People who engage in edit wars know about editing as much as Jon Snow knows. BTW, where is according to scriptures here? Is it a bug I can't see?

Comment: @Pandya i saw ur meta post refarding diff bw i-r & scripture tag....which one is applicable here? :)

Comment: Practice tag. Because you are asking about a practice i.e., bathing. Scripture is for questions on texts when you ask _about_  Vedas, Brahmanas, etc., that is not needed when you add specific tag like [puranas], [vedas] etc., ID (not i-r) tag is for searching a source of a verse or a story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a partial answer:

Varuna, Agneya, Vayabya etc - these forms of baths are mentioned in various scriptures. My reference here is **Pararshara Smriti's 12th chapter**.

> [image]
>
> **SnAnAni pancha punyAni** kirtitAni manishibhihi |
>  Agneyam vArunam brAhmam vAyabyam divyameva cha ||
>
> 9. The learned have declared five kinds of bathing to purificatory : the Agneya or fiery bathing, the Varuna or the watery bathing, the
>      Brahma or Vedic bathing, the VAyavya or windy bathing, and the Divya
>      or the celestial bathing
>
> 10 — 11. The Agneya bathing consists in bathing with ashes ; the
>   Varuna is plunging into the water ; the Brahma consists in reciting
>   the verse ' apohishta, &c. ;' the Vayavya is bathing with the dust
>   raised by the hoof of a cow ; but the celestial bathing takes place
>   when one is drenched with, rain-water, the rain coming down while the
>   sun is shining. This kind of bathing is of equal efficacy with the
>   bathing in the river Ganga.

So, this scripture is talking about five kinds of baths.

**UPDATE:**

**Nitya SnAna:**

This is the daily mandatory bath that one should perform everyday at early morning (preferably before the sun rises).

**Naimittika SnAna:**

This is an occasional bath which is done for a particular reason for e.g. Grahana baths (baths after eclipses), SmkrAnti baths or baths when a particular impurity (Asaucha) has ended.

**KAmmya SnAna:**

This is a bath done keeping a specific purpose in mind. Examples will be baths taken in holy Tirthas/rivers.

These three kinds of baths are mentioned in Daksha Smriti for example:

> Bathing has been spoken of as being threefold, viz. Nitya (daily),
>   Naimitika (obligatory, as in the solar or lunar eclipse), and Kamya
>   (having an end, such as the attainment of the celestial region in
>   view;. (37)

Comment: Thanks...any reference for Muni Snanam, Deva Snanam, Manava Snanam and Rakshasa Snanam which I got to know that have time associated with them 4-5am, 5-6am, 6-8am, 8am+..

Comment: No at this moment I can't recall reading anything abt those kinds of bath @YDS

Comment: I hv updated reg Nitya/Naimittika etc .. @YDS

Comment: @Rickross Any references to Avabrudha Snana?

Comment: No I don't know abt that  @Ambi

Answer (score 1):

Bhagavan Srikantha deva (dakshinamurty) describes the 6 types of snan in the Kamika Agama Purvapada, snana vidhi pathalam.

> atha snāna vidhiṁ vakṣye parameśa prakāśitam| 
>    sarvadoṣaharaṁ puṇyaṁ manaḥprītikaraṁ param|| 1 
>    vāruṇañca tathāgneyaṁ māntra mānasameva ca| 
>    vāyavyañca mahendrākhyaṁ snānaṁ ṣaḍvidhamīritam|| 2

Then, I will explain various ceremonial methods of taking the daily bath as revealed by Lord 
Paramesvara. Such bath is capable of warding off all sorts of defilement; it is auspicious and 
meritorious; efficacious in yielding a serene state of contentment to the mind; it is of supreme 
nature. There are six kinds of ceremonial ablution – watery, fiery, mantric, mentally performable, 
airy and the one related to sunshine, rain and dust( varuna, agneya, mantra, manasa, vayavya 
and the mahendra).

Comment: The credits section is not relevant to the question. Please remove it to improve the quality of your answer.